# how to print double loop output in one line using tqdm

Tags: python, tqdm

I want to print double loop output in one line using tqdm

I Try:

```
from tqdm import tqdm

epochs = 3
num_batch=5
for epoch_step in range(epochs):
    with tqdm(range(num_batch)) as pbar:
        for batch_step in pbar:
            pbar.set_description(f"Epochs {epoch_step+1}/{epochs}")
            pbar.set_postfix({'batch loss': 'This is batch loss' })
        pbar.set_postfix({'epoch loss': 'This is epoch loss'})
```

and Expecting output:

```
Epochs 1/3: 100%|██████████| 5/5 [00:00<00:00, 890.13it/s, batch loss=This is epoch loss]
Epochs 2/3: 100%|██████████| 5/5 [00:00<00:00, 677.24it/s, batch loss=This is epoch loss]
Epochs 3/3: 100%|██████████| 5/5 [00:00<00:00, 969.78it/s, batch loss=This is epoch loss]
```

But this are real output:

```
Epochs 1/3: 100%|██████████| 5/5 [00:00<00:00, 890.13it/s, batch loss=This is batch loss]
Epochs 2/3: 100%|██████████| 5/5 [00:00<00:00, 677.24it/s, batch loss=This is batch loss]
Epochs 3/3: 100%|██████████| 5/5 [00:00<00:00, 969.78it/s, batch loss=This is batch loss]
```

How I try to fix my code to get expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're going for:

```
epochs = 3
num_batch=5
for epoch_step in range(epochs):
    pbar = tqdm(range(num_batch))
    pbar.set_postfix({'epoch loss': 'This is epoch loss'})
    time.sleep(2)
    for batch_step in pbar:
        pbar.set_description(f"Epochs {epoch_step+1}/{epochs}")
        pbar.set_postfix({'batch loss': 'This is batch loss' })
        time.sleep(2)
```

You can also use tqdm.trange() instead of tqdm.tqdm(range())